Unpack TypeVar bound to TypedDict
II'm trying to do something like this, so, be able to make a generic python class with different types, but annotate so that the IDE can give the possibility of.
from typing import AsyncIterator, Generic, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Unpack, TypedDict
from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)


class _Filter(TypedDict, total=False):
    pass


F = TypeVar("F", bound=_Filter)


class API(Generic[T, F]):
    def __init__(self, client: HttpClient, url: str):
        self._client = client
        self._url = url

    async def filter(self, *args, **kwargs:Unpack[F]) -> AsyncIterator[T]:
        pass

But **kwargs:Unpack[F] it looks like it's not working well, my IDE does not detect possible arguments.
On VsCode, pylance say : Expected TypedDict type argument for Unpack.
Maybe I'm going the wrong way, or maybe what I want to do isn't possible.
I would like the IDE not to be lost and to know that it is possible to have this or that parameter.

Unfortunately not possible. See https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1399. You should avoid TypedDict entirely and take in a @dataclass / BaseModel like you already imported instead. Only downside is the slightly more verbose interface compared to kwargs.

I'll look into it, thanks
